# How to get more than one parent control in form

Tags: vb.net

Newbie here :)

In order to achieve a transparency-type effect for pictureboxcharacter1 on the background, I have set pictureboxbackground1 as its parent.
this works fine.

For the second picturebox (on the same form) I tried the same thing and set pictureboxbackground2 as its parent so it would look transparent over pictureboxbackground2. However when I debug the application pictureboxcharacter2 disappears and only pictureboxbackground2 is visible.

the code I have is:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Me.pictureboxcharacter1.Parent = Me.pictureboxbackground1
  Me.pictureboxcharacter2.Parent = Me.pictureboxbackground2
End Sub
```

Really strange: if I put pictureboxcharacter2 on pictureboxbackground1 in the designer tab, while debugging it shows up on picturebackground2 and transparent (like how I wanted it to be)??
Does anyone know what's going on at all?
Please I'm NEED any help I could get

Comment: If you want full control over transparency use `WPF`.

Comment: Transparent in NET means "use parent's background color".  there is a way around it (in winforms) by subclassing the control

Answer (score 0):

Is pictureboxcharacter1 and pictureboxcharacter2 one over other ? If so try making the one be other's parent.
Have a play with bring to front option and see if that works.